# Optional parameters to arguments along with sub commands using argparse

Tags: python, arguments, argparse, option-type, subcommand

I'm having trouble trying to allow for optional test parameters to be inserted into CLI I'm created.  Here's what I've able to do:

```
python test.py --test build --name foobar
```

Where build is a subcommand, and --test allows for the system to point to the default test server.  However, I would like to allow users to specified an additional, optional, server property after the --test so users can point the test server whereever they want.  Example:

```
python test.py --test "<random http>" build --name foobar
```

My code currently looks like this:

```
    main_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    main_parser.add_argument('--test', action='store', nargs=1, dest='test_server', help='Use test server')

    subparsers = main_parser.add_subparsers(help='SubCommands', dest='command')

    build_parser = subparsers.add_parser('build', help = 'lists the build command(s) for the specified view/warehouse')
    build_parser.add_argument('--name', action='store', nargs=1, dest='build_name')
```

However, no matter what I change the nargs to, it starts disallow the original, which is just --test.  Is there a way I can have both?

Comment: *optional*? and how it's supposed to tell whether the next word is the optional parameter or the next argument? your grammar is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an optional nargs, using `nargs='?'`, but as Karoly Horvath states, your grammar is ambiguous. You be much better off adding --test to your build subparser

```
main_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = main_parser.add_subparsers(help='SubCommands', dest='command')

build_parser = subparsers.add_parser('build', help = 'lists the build command(s) for the specified view/warehouse')
build_parser.add_argument('--test', action='store', nargs='?', dest='test_server', help='Use test server')
build_parser.add_argument('--name', action='store', nargs=1, dest='build_name')
```

Then your syntax would be:

```
python test.py build --test "<random http>" --name foobar
```

try looking at [`argparse#nargs`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#nargs)